# Identifying data points above fixed effects regression using data.table

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, plm

**I want to identify the data points above a regression line.** I have a panel data set which I have fit a fixed effects model:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   progenyMean = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   damMean = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89)

ID, year, progenyMean, damMean
1, 1, 70, 69
1, 2, 68, 69
1, 3, 72, 72
1, 4, 69, 68
2, 1, 76, 75
2, 2, 73, 80
3, 1, 72, 74
3, 2, 75, 67
3, 3, 71, 69

# Fixed Effects Model in plm
fixed <- plm(progenyMean ~ damMean, data, model= "within", index = c("ID","year"))
```

I have plotted `progenyMean` vs `damMean` with the fixed effects regression line:
[image]

**I want to identify the `ID`'s above this regression line.**
I have computed the predicted values of the fixed effects model using the following code (based off code from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147350/computing-the-predicted-value-from-a-panel-data-model-with-the-plm-r-package))

```
fitted <- as.numeric(fixed$model[[1]] - fixed$residuals)
> fitted
 [1]  71.24338  79.03766  74.86613  71.34263  70.83020  71.56797  72.17324  74.54755  71.16720  73.37487
[11]  70.58863  69.27203  71.05852  59.72911  63.43947  68.69871  67.25271  75.68397  76.30475  81.12128
```

Is it possible to identify the `ID`'s above the fixed effects regression line using the predicted values above and `data.table` in R?

Answer (score 1):

Use `residuals` function. Positive residual = points above the line, negative = points below the line.

```
library(plm)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   progenyMean = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   damMean = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89))

fixed <- plm(progenyMean ~ damMean, data, model= "within", index = c("ID","year"))                   
residuals(fixed)

data %>% ggplot(aes(damMean, progenyMean)) +
  geom_point(data=data %>% filter(residuals(fixed)>0), col="red")+
  geom_point(data=data %>% filter(residuals(fixed)<0), col="blue")

data %>% mutate(
  test = ifelse(residuals(fixed)>0, "up", "down") %>% factor()
) %>% group_by(test) %>% summarise(
  n = n()
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do so using `data.table`? And to create a new data table with `ID`'s above and below?

Comment: I have created the following list of data points above/below the regression line:
`> fitted <- as.numeric(fixed$model[[1]] - fixed$residuals)
above <- data$progenyMean3Y > fitted`
But I'm unsure how to create a table using data.table where each row is a unique ID and there are two columns, above and below which count the number of data points above/below the regression line for that ID?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. See my edited answer. Was this what you expected? One more thing, are you absolutely sure you want to use the `plm` model instead of the standard `lm`?